# Matlab fwrite precision conversion

Tags: matlab, fwrite

I want to write some data to a binary file in `single` precision. The data is originally in `double` precision. Is there any difference between converting the data to `single` by calling the `single` command before `fwrite` and just letting Matlab do the conversion in the `fwrite` call?

Case 1

```
data1 % double precision
fwrite(fid,data1,'single');
```

Case 2

```
data2=single(data1);
fwrite(fid,data2,'single');
```

In the 2nd case, is Matlab doing any modifications to data2 before writing it since it is already in `single` format ? Will there be any difference in data written to the two files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
data1 = 1.555555555555555555;
data2 = single(data1);

fid = fopen('C:\Some\Address\data1.bin', 'w');
fwrite(fid, data1, 'single');
fclose(fid);

fid = fopen('C:\Some\Address\data2.bin', 'w');
fwrite(fid, data2, 'single');
fclose(fid);

% Lets read them back (note that MATLAB stores them in a double-precision variable by default)
fid = fopen('C:\Some\Address\data1.bin', 'r');
data1 = fread(fid, 'single');
fclose(fid);
fid = fopen('C:\Some\Address\data2.bin', 'r');
data2 = fread(fid, 'single');
fclose(fid);

format long;
[data1 data2] % or use fprintf to see the values

ans =

   1.555555582046509   1.555555582046509
```

To your questions:

> In the 2nd case, is Matlab doing any modifications to data2 before
> writing it since it is already in single format ?

I don't think so but cannot be confident without knowing what is going on under the hood of `fwrite`.

> Will there be any difference in data written to the two files ?

According to the test above I don't believe so,

Answer (score 3):

You should use `formatSpec` to specify the format:

[image]

Like this

```
A = [6.6,1.11111];
formatSpec = '%4.5f'; % modify it accordingly.
fprintf(formatSpec ,A);
```

Comment: OP wants to write to a *binary* file, not a text file. `fwrite` and `fprintf` do very different things.